# Obtener valor de un actionResult en la vista

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor

Quiero obtener la respuesta de un actionResult en la vista. Estoy trabajando con Blazor y soy nueva en esto, es mi primer proyecto.

Les mostrare mi código.
Este es mi controlador:
Obtengo el valor de un procedimiento almacenado desde mysql

```
[HttpPost("{seleccion}")]
public async Task <ActionResult> Post(Calendario calendario, string seleccion)
{
    var retorno = new MySqlParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "@respuesta",
        DbType = DbType.Int32,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    };
    var respuesta= context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("call spGCalendario ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4}out)",
        seleccion,
        calendario.FincaId,
        calendario.CintaId,
        calendario.FechaInicial.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        retorno.Value);
    return Ok(respuesta);
}
```

No se como puedo obtener la variable respuesta en la vista.
Aqui esta el codigo de la vista:

```
private async Task Crear()
{
    var httpResponse = await repositorioCalendario.AddCalendario($"api/calendario/{respuestaSeleccion}", calendario);
    var res = httpResponse.HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode;
    if (httpResponse.Error)
    {
        var body = await httpResponse.HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Respuesta",res);
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("/calendario/indexCalendario");
    }
}
```

y este es mi repositorio:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseWrapper<object>> AddCalendario<T>(string url, T enviar)
{
    var enviarJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(enviar);
    var enviarContent = new StringContent(enviarJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var responseHttp = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, enviarContent);
    return new HttpResponseWrapper<object>(null, !responseHttp.IsSuccessStatusCode, responseHttp);
}
```